# .NET CLR Perfmon = Correlate against Windows service(name)?

Tags: c#, windows, perfmon

Currently monitoring the memory usage for Dynamics NAV.
The process is called "Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server" and the service is called "Microsoft.Dynamics.NAV.Server$MyNAVInstance.

However when launching Perfmon and monitoring the memory under ".NET CLR Memory" I can only see:
"Microsoft.Dynamics.NAV.Server"
"Microsoft.Dynamics.NAV.Server#1"
and so on.

How can I correlate the "CLR"-name in Perfmon to the Windows service(name)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct metric under "Processes" and was also under the same found the PID and was able to identify the PID and corralate against the service